# Angular ng-click with call to a function not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I am trying to switch views from one page to another when a button is pressed.I am using ng-click for it but it doesnt switch the views when the button is pressed

.js file

```
$scope.onCreateAppointment = function () {

              $scope.templates.myTemplate = "views/calendar.html";

            };

        }]);
```

.html file

```
    ng-click="OnCreateAppointment()">Create Appointment</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive.  The method "OnCreateAppointment()" doesn't exist on the scope.

The fix is:

```
 <button ng-click="onCreateAppointment()">Create Appointment</button>
```